# Laravel Eloquent how to query with multiple 'froms'?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How do I convert a query like this to eloquent:

```
select table1.column, table2.column, table3.column from table1, table2, table3
```

Comment: are those tables related to each other with foreign key?

Comment: As this query will not give any results until they are connected in some way. You can use Laravel Relationships - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You can use achieve this by

```
DB::query()
  ->from('table1, table2, table3')
  ->select('table1.column', 'table2.column', 'table3.column')
  ->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fromRaw()`:

```php
DB::query()
    ->select('table1.column', 'table2.column', 'table3.column')
    ->fromRaw('table1, table2, table3')
    ->get();
```

Comment: This query will not give any results.

Comment: Yes, it does. It creates the query from the question.

Comment: it will give blank resultset. as there is no where condition to find records based on connection. there should be some connection between those tables to find records.